# Executing .bat files from Powershell via Ansible

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible

I am using Ansible to execute a Powershell script on several Windows hosts. In the Powershell script, I am using `Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "C:\Path\to\some\bat\file.bat"`

The bat files are several programs that run indefinitely.

The issue I'm having is that when I run the Powershell script manually, everything works. The bat files are executed and done. When I execute the file via Ansible, the bat files are not executed. No errors reported that I could find.

Any idea how I can get these two bat files up and running via Ansible?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run a batch file in windows using ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776217/run-a-batch-file-in-windows-using-ansible)

Comment: How are you running those scripts from Ansible ? What does your playbook look like ? Did you run your playbook with `-vvv` (and looked at the output) ? If you have useful answers to any of those questions, please edit your question and add the necessary details for others to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

#### use win_command

```
- name: Simple batch script
  win_command: "C:\Path\to\some\bat\file.bat"
```

You can use `win_shell` too.